# NullReferenceException when trying to get child elements of an XElement

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a feeling that this is going to be a really simple solution, but I just can't figure it out.

I have the following Linq statement:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> children = from element in xElement.Descendants(xNamespace + "Email") select element;
foreach (XElement element in children)
     Console.WriteLine(element);
```

When I execute it in LINQPad, I get a series of XML blocks, as I expect.  For example:

```
<Email xmlns="https://xxxxxx/Email">
  <user xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">someuser</user>
  <host xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">somehost.com</host>
</Email>
```

But if I change the last line to:

```
     Console.WriteLine(element.Element("user").Value);
```

I get a `NullReferenceException`, which doesn't make sense to me.  Is there something different I need to do in order to be able to grab the values of those child objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the namespace:

```
 Console.WriteLine(element.Element(xNamespace + "user").Value);
```